# Receiving wrong status line: "HTTP/1.1 1 CUSTOM" when making POST request

Tags: ruby, http, post, request

I've been trying to figure this one out for a few days now, and I am out of ideas. I have the following code that makes a `POST` request to another instance of an application running locally.

The HTTP request is initialized by the following code:

```
http_client = Net::HTTP.new(0.0.0.0, 1344)
http_client.use_ssl = true
http_client.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/some-path/?#some=params", {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
request.set_form_data(options[:post_data]) if options[:post_data]
request.body = options[:request_body] if options[:request_body]

response = http_client.request(request)
```

When I run the above, I get the following error:

```
#<Net::HTTPBadResponse: wrong status line: "HTTP/1.1 1 CUSTOM">
```

Looking at that, it seemed the issue stems from `http_client.request(request)`'s headers have some issues. I tried to debug it by logging `response.to_hash.inspect`, but I am unable to because it throws an exception before I could execute the above inspection.

I did some [Googling](http://www.antleon.com/2015/06/resolve-nethttpbadresponse-wrong-status-line/), and it mentioned that I should have `use_ssl = true`, which I did. Still getting the same error.

The `url` is `0.0.0.0` because I am running this locally, and `1344` is the port.

Answer (score 0):

you should use encoding while using https/ssl. Try this:

```
uri = URI.encode("/some-path/?#some=params")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

Comment: Still getting the same exception

Comment: I've tried using encoding and get the same error. Did you ever find this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem is on server-side, not client (calling) side.

Server code returns HTTP status **1**, not **200**, **404** or other standardized protocol value.

When rails server code controller returns:

```
render json: {}, status: 1
```

generated HTTP response starts with:

```
HTTP/1.1 1 CUSTOM
```

causing error like yours.

Another example - server code:

```
render json: {}, status: 'mistyped'
```

renders

```
HTTP/1.1 0 CUSTOM
```